# google crawlererror how to fix it

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I rewrite my site completely and now google show 17000 link errors from the old site. what's the best solution for this as i cannot manually remove one by one url or disallow one by one to robots.txt

Can a new sitemap help to resolve this ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this: http://moz.com/blog/how-to-fix-crawl-errors-in-google-webmaster-tools

That is the only thing that I can really tell you. A new sitemap should resolve this.